# cmake: statically link against opencv libs

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

On Ubuntu 20.04:

`sudo apt install libopencv-dev`

Result:

```
kwu@Dev-KWu:/usr$ find . -name "*opencv_imgproc*" -o -name "*opencv_core*"
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.4.2
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.2.0
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.a
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.a
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.2
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.4.2.0
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
set(OpenCV_SHARED OFF) # found on internet, makes no difference to resulting ninja.build
set(OpenCV_STATIC ON) # found on internet, makes no difference to resulting ninja.build
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED COMPONENTS imgproc core)
...
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Result in ninja.build:

`LINK_LIBRARIES = ... /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.2.0  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.4.2.0 ...`

What's the magic sauce to link against OpenCV statically?

Comment: You need to compile OpenCV from source with `USE_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`. The libraries that come with apt are dynamic.

Comment: apt had installed the static libraries, too - see the file listing in my post.

Comment: You may want to inspect `OpenCVConfig.cmake` at installation directory. On Windows, I see that setting `OpenCV_STATIC` or `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` has an effect on linker directory. Nevertheless, compiling from source should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

After examining OpenCVConfig.cmake, typically, I expected to *set(OpenCV_SHARED OFF)* before *find_package(OpenCV...)* to do the job. However, I needed to do it manually. If your cmake supports *list(TRANSFORM)*, which I guess it does, do the following:

```
...
# replace .so files with .a files for static linking.
list(TRANSFORM ${OpenCV_LIBS} REPLACE "(^[A-Za-z0-9/\\_-]+)(\.so)" "\\1.a" OpenCV_LIBS)
# you can output the result to ensure it is right
message(STATUS ${OpenCV_LIBS})
...
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```